# How do I install Python 2.7.10 to a conda environment?

Tags: python, package, conda, miniconda, conda-forge

I need this specific version for a legacy project. This version is not included neither in the default package repository nor in the Conda Forge. How can I install this specific version to a miniconda environment? I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: This is highly os-specific. Have you tried to google for solutions online with respect to your OS? If yes, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @TYZ I edited the question with the OS. I tried searching online but so far no solution

Comment: If you already have anaconda installed, have you tried to create python2.7 environment via: `conda create --name py2 python=2.7`?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've been able to find is to use pyenv, which is not convenient at all as whichever version you choose is global and whatever conda environment you have active is effectively ignored :/